# how to configure sonar in tfs 2015 for .net core project

Tags: .net, tfs, sonarqube

I have always this problem.

2016-10-20T09:32:52.6982011Z Executing the powershell script: C:\Agents\agent\tasks\SonarQubePostTest\1.0.37\SonarQubePostTest.ps1
2016-10-20T09:32:53.7060658Z SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1
2016-10-20T09:32:53.7070421Z Default properties file was not found at C:\Agents\agent\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.35\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
2016-10-20T09:32:53.7081233Z Post-processing started.
2016-10-20T09:32:53.8105393Z SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild End Step 2.1
2016-10-20T09:32:53.8105393Z 11:32:53.606  Fetching code coverage report information from TFS...
2016-10-20T09:32:53.8116042Z 11:32:53.641  Attempting to locate a test results (.trx) file...
2016-10-20T09:32:53.8125127Z 11:32:53.642  No test results files found
2016-10-20T09:32:53.8125127Z ##[error]No analysable projects were found. SonarQube analysis will not be performed. Check the build summary report for details.
2016-10-20T09:32:53.8125127Z Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
2016-10-20T09:32:53.8144208Z 11:32:53.765  Creating a summary markdown file...
2016-10-20T09:32:53.8144208Z ##[error]Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2016-10-20T09:32:53.8222795Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1
2016-10-20T09:32:53.8495949Z The build was not set to fail if the associated quality gate fails.

Answer (score 4):

The tooling around .NET Core is not finalized yet, so the SonarQube Scanner for MsBuild which heavily relies on the build tooling does not support .NET Core yet. Microsoft is moving the .xproj to .csproj, and all build to use MsBuild. We might not even have to change anything in the end to support .NET Core.

Comment: there exists a similar tool ?!